# How to set one session for multiple asp.net core apps in the Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, session, azure-active-directory, microservices

How to set one session for multiple asp.net core 3.1 microservices with Azure Active Directory authentication?

Comment: All services are deployed in Azure.

Comment: Does the [single sign-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on) meet your requirement?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use just one access token to access mutiple azure protected resources?

Comment: For example, we have two instances of two different services and the user should have one session object with the same session id and session parameters for each instance. The purpose is to audit all user actions on all services and group it by session.

Comment: you can try with Azure redis cache which helps you to maintain single session in case of multiple instances and will be able to get session information through it